# permissionOverwrites does not notice permissions given to @everyone role. How can I solve that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanted to create a script that when a person connects to specific voice-channel it creates a room which only that person can join and others can't.

The script's logic is simple; it creates permissions for the person who connected to the channel (speak, voice activity, etc.) and denies `CONNECT` permission from the `@everyone` role.

The problem is that my bot gives permissions to the person who connected to the voice channel but does not change any permission of the `@everyone` role. How can I solve that?

```
const { VoiceState } = require('discord.js');
const SettingsJSON = require('../../Configuration/Settings.json');
const Settings = SettingsJSON.PrivHub;

module.exports = async (oldState, newState) => {
  let mainChannel = oldState.guild.channels.cache.get(Settings.Room);
  if (!mainChannel) return;

  if (
    !oldState.channelID &&
    newState.channelID &&
    newState.channel.parentID == mainChannel.parentID &&
    newState.channelID == mainChannel.id
  ) {
    newState.guild.channels
      .create(
        `${Settings.Symbol} ${newState.member.displayName} kişisinin odası`,
        {
          type: 'voice',
          parent: mainChannel.parentID,
          permissionOverwrites: [
            mainChannel.permissionOverwrites.clone().set(
              newState.member.id,
              {
                id: newState.member.id,
                allow: [
                  'MANAGE_CHANNELS',
                  'STREAM',
                  'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                  'CONNECT',
                  'SPEAK',
                  'USE_VAD',
                ],
              },
              {
                id: oldState.guild.roles.everyone.id,
                deny: ["CONNECT"],
              },
            ),
          ],
        },
      )
      .then((channel) => {
        if (newState.member && newState.member.voice.channelID)
          newState.member.voice.setChannel(channel);
      });
    return;
  } else if (oldState.channelID && newState.channelID) {
    let oldChannel = oldState.channel;
    if (
      oldChannel.position > mainChannel.position &&
      oldChannel.parentID == mainChannel.parentID &&
      oldChannel.members.size <= 0 &&
      !oldChannel.deleted
    )
      oldChannel.delete().catch(undefined);
    if (
      newState.channelID == mainChannel.id &&
      newState.channel.parentID == mainChannel.parentID
    ) {
      newState.guild.channels
        .create(
          `${Settings.Symbol} ${newState.member.displayName} kişisinin odası`,
          {
            type: 'voice',
            parent: mainChannel.parentID,
            permissionOverwrites: [
              mainChannel.permissionOverwrites.clone().set(
                newState.member.id,
                {
                  id: newState.member.id,
                  allow: [
                    'MANAGE_CHANNELS',
                    'STREAM',
                    'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                    'CONNECT',
                    'SPEAK',
                    'USE_VAD',
                  ],
                },
                {
                id: oldState.guild.roles.everyone.id,
                deny: ["CONNECT"],
                },
              ),
            ],
          },
        )
        .then((channel) => {
          if (newState.member && newState.member.voice.channelID)
            newState.member.voice.setChannel(channel);
        });
    }
    return;
  } else if (
    oldState.channelID &&
    oldState.channel.parentID == mainChannel.parentID &&
    !newState.channelID
  ) {
    let oldChannel = oldState.channel;
    if (
      oldChannel.position > mainChannel.position &&
      oldChannel.members.size <= 0 &&
      !oldChannel.deleted
    )
      oldChannel.delete().catch(undefined);
  }
};

module.exports.config = {
  Event: 'voiceStateUpdate',
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you clone the collection `mainChannel.permissionOverwrites`, you only use the `set()` method with the key `newState.member.id`.

The [`set()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=set) method only accepts two arguments, the key and the value of the element to add. In your code above you use three arguments, first the key, second an object with the `allow` property, and lastly another object with the `deny` property (which should be used for the `@everyone` role).

In JavaScript, if you pass some extra arguments when a function only needs two, nothing happens, it just ignores it. That's what happens here. You only set the first overwrite with the `allow` prop.

To fix this, you could use two `set()` methods; one for the member, and one for the `@everyone` role:

```js
{
  type: 'voice',
  parent: mainChannel.parentID,
  permissionOverwrites: [
    mainChannel.permissionOverwrites
      .clone()
      .set(newState.member.id, {
        id: newState.member.id,
        allow: [
          'MANAGE_CHANNELS',
          'STREAM',
          'VIEW_CHANNEL',
          'CONNECT',
          'SPEAK',
          'USE_VAD',
        ],
      })
      .set(oldState.guild.roles.everyone.id, {
        id: oldState.guild.roles.everyone.id,
        deny: ['CONNECT'],
      }),
  ],
}
```